# Determine of the colour of laser

Tags: circuit-design, light-sensor, colour-coding

I am currently working on a project which requires the the circuit to perform specific task if a specific colour of laser is detected (something like a basic remote control). Is there a sensor or a way to make LDRs sensitive to only one colour of light.

I tried to find the solution but each time I end up with solutions involving Colour sensor which detects the reflected light from a coloured object not the colour of light.

Comment: A prism or diffraction grating with detectors positioned correctly would possibly work. You don't specify the type of laser, how monochromatic each color is, etc. So it's hard to say for sure. But it could be as easy is just taking a rewritable DVD disc as a diffraction grating. With just that stupid DVD disc and a cardboard box I made with a razor blade and tape, I can easily split the mercury doublet at 576.959 nm and 579.065 nm (yellow-orange.) So you can build something really cheap under the right circumstances.

Comment: You could use optical filters over a photodiode, but why you can't use an infrared system is confusing.

Comment: There are also laser dyes. These can be applied directly to the diode detectors in use. There are also, of course, the obvious and expensive thin film filters. But then you might also need a beam splitter. So more money. And you can use various other techniques, like applying a thin gold covering over the diode detector and applying a voltage to drive photo-generated electrons into the depletion region to emphasize capture of certain photons. Too bad you aren't disclosing more details. Astronomers know almost all the tricks in the trade. I read what they write.

Comment: Aadarsh Ganesh Goenka - Hi, Some good points already above, but your actual *question* is unclear. (a) You said: "*I tried to find the solution*" Solution to what, *exactly*? What *specific* issue meant previous attempted solutions (please list them) didn't meet a *specific* constraint (please explain)? (b) You said: "*Is there a sensor or a way to make LDRs sensitive to only one colour of light.*" Why do you mention LDRs? Must you use those? Or are you asking if there is any other sensor sensitive to only 1 colour? Why not post-process a multi-colour sensor's output? Please add more details!

Comment: Your title does not match your question. Are you trying to *determine* the wavelength of a laser? Or are you trying to detect a laser of a single known wavelength?

Comment: I am new to this community so I didn't have much experience here so I am sorry if I created some confusion with my question. The thing is I have Red Green and Blue lasers on my remote and the circuit should detect which combination of lasers has been activated, and in turn perform a task. I want to know if there are sensors which are sensitive to only one colour of light so that it is easier to detect seperate lasers easily and later if needed more colours can be included.

Answer (score 2):

> I am currently working on a project which requires the the circuit to perform specific task if a specific colour of laser is detected (something like a basic remote control). Is there a sensor or a way to make LDRs sensitive to only one colour of light.

While there are many solutions for making spectrally resolved detectors (diffraction gratings, prisms, dielectric filters), the overwhelming most common approach used in remote controls is to put a simple piece of colored glass in front of the sensor.  Light not matching the desired color is absorbed.

You might wonder why such simple methods are preferred.  The reason is that absorptive filters are very, very cheap and they can be made arbitrarily selective by simply making the glass thicker, which will **exponentially** increase its absorption.  For this reason, even a few cents worth of colored plastic can often be highly effective.  If better absorption is required, there are also speciality glasses designed for absorption of specific wavelengths.  See for example: https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=999

(note that glasses are available from many vendors, so you can often buy them for a tiny fraction of the list price online)

For applications where two lasers are very close in wavelength (tens of nanometers apart or less) there are also dichroic filters, which can have extremely specific pass bands.  However, these are orders of magnitude more expensive, very fragile, and must be kept clean or their selectivity is degraded.

Answer (score 0):

Your title does not match your question.

If you want to *determine* the colour of the laser, there are photodiodes whose construction consists of two overlapping photodiodes on the same substrate. The photodiodes have different responsivity curves and the result is that if you expose a monochromatic wavelength to it, the outputs of the two photodiodes will be unique and allow you to identify the wavelength. It won't work when also exposed to ambient light though...unless the laser overwhelms ambient light, I suppose.

But if you are only trying to detect a known wavelength then just get an interference (dichroic) filter and stick it over a photodiode. Filters can be expensive though and it could be cheaper to go with the above method (even though those photodiodes are also quite expensive).

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to detect which of several quite different light sources is on, consider using several general-purpose photodetectors with coloured filters in front.  This works well when you have red and green, for example.

You can get very good "colour gel swatches" from theatrical lighting suppliers.  Many come in a book with the spectrum printed for each filter.  Just experiment with different combinations of colours until you get the selectivity you need.

[image]